# Dbcontext lifecycle in windows service

Tags: .net, entity-framework, windows-services

I am using a windows service that pings other services every 10 minutes and based on their response does some calculations.

Calculation result datamodel is very simple and I am ending up with around 1000 objects per 10 min cycle that need to be persisted to the db. For this I am using entity framework code first.

From performance perspective what would be a better approach:

1) Create Dbcontext on service start and keep it during service lifetime to persist the data (delete unnecessary, update existing and insert new objects to the db)

2) Create Dbcontext on each cycle (10 min), drop all existing data from the db (as previous versions are not needed), insert new data and dispose of Dbcontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

> 2) Create Dbcontext on each cycle (10 min), drop all existing data
>   from the db (as previous versions are not needed), insert new data and
>   dispose of Dbcontext

The `DbContext` will maintain a cache of the entities it has touched, and you wouldn't want that to persist and grow over a long time.